# Rounding in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a list of numbers in column A that go to several decimal places (e.g. A1 is `27.34`). Is there a way to fill column B with the same values as column A, but rounding to the nearest integer?

Comment: cpast's edit changed the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula in B1

`=INT(A1)`

Answer (score 1):

excel has a floor() funcion

floor()

The syntax for the FLOOR function is:

FLOOR( number, significance )

number is the number that you wish to round down.

significance is the multiple of significance that you wish to round a number to.

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/floor.php

Answer (score 1):

Another way, without using functions, is to use the [Decrease Decimal button](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-the-decimal-places-displayed-for-numbers-HP001216499.aspx) from the Number group in the Home tab.

[image]

Comment: This will only change the _display_ of the number, not the value in the cell, though.

Answer (score 1):

`FLOOR` and `ROUND( <cellreference> , 0)` will have different behavior for negative numbers.

`ROUND(-27.3, 0)` will give you -27. But the highest integer that's less than -27.3 will be -28.

For positive numbers, `FLOOR` is also only going to provide you with the nearest integer if the portion after the decimal place is less than 0.5; otherwise `ROUND ( <cellreference>, 0)` will be better to use if you want the nearest integer in all situations.

`TRUNC` just gets rid of everything after the decimal place; but again, for positive numbers, that won't give you the closest integer all the time, only for numbers where the non-integer part is less than 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=FLOOR(A1,1)` in cell B1 :-)

Comment: Adding some explanation of why this answers the question would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TRUNC function.

i.e. B1 =TRUNC(A1)

Comment: An explanation of why this works would make this a better answer.

Comment: Maybe include what's happening (why this works)?

Answer (score 0):

Click cell B1 , type `TRUNC(`, then click cell A1, add a `)` and press enter. This should put the correct number in B2, which you can then drag the corner of to cell B100 to fill every cell with the proper formula.

Comment: Darn, you guys type fast...

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [RoundDown function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rounddown-HP005209241.aspx), as it is designed specifically for what you are asking.

It takes two arguments, the first being the number [or cell reference] you want to round down, the second being the amount of decimals it should have.

Examples:

=ROUNDDOWN(3.1456,0) becomes 3

=ROUNDDOWN(3.1456,1) becomes 3.1

=ROUNDDOWN(3.1456,2) becomes 3.14

=ROUNDDOWN(3.1456,3) becomes 3.145

=ROUNDDOWN(3.1456,4) becomes 3.1456